# Running a function if if its keyword is in a specific range is in a list

Tags: python, command-line-interface

I had a list of word that when typed, would run a specific function and if a word was not in the list then it would print out "Not Valid!"

```
commLineInput = input("Input Command: ")



commandList = ["calculator","security"]

def commSlctandRun():
 if commLineInput == commandList in range (0,10) : 
    return commandList(commLineInput)
 else:
    print("Not valid!")
```

.Can anyone explain what i need to do

it would compare the input and the words in the list within the first 11 entries of the list and if not in the list it would print out as invalid . The result was that the code would run but after running the function it would print out "Not Valid!"

Answer (score 0):

I have a bit of difficulty to understand what you want to do exactly, but here some cue:

You can easily know if an `element` is inside à list:

```py
list_of_things = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]

element = "a"

if element in liste_of_things:
    print(f"{element} is in list_of_things")
```

If you want to limitate the length of the list:

```py
if element in liste_of_things[:10]:
    print(f"{element} is in the 10 first element of list_of_things")
```

Hope that will help.

Now, about your code:

```py
commandList = ["calculator","security"]
...
    if commLineInput == commandList in range (0,10) : 
        return commandList(commLineInput)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

`commandList` is not a function, it's a list, you can call it like that. Even with square braket it won't work, you have to use `int` to specify the index. You can also get the index from an element `commandList.index(commLineInput)` which could be useful to know the position of the first element matching `commLineInput` of the list.

Also:

```py
if commLineInput == commandList in range(0,10):
```

I'm know sure how Python will interpret this... my guess, it will do the comparison et look it the result is in the `range(0, 10)`. The comparison will be `True` or `False` so the final result will be `False` since `range(0, 10)` give en iterator of integer and not boolean.

Comment: both of the words in the list activate functions when typed e.g

`  def calculatorFunc():
 if commLineInput == "calculator":
     if (commLineInput == "calculator") == True:
         calcFuncInput = input("Input Expression: ")
         print(eval(calcFuncInput))
`
That is for "calculator"